# The textblock in a circle

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cross-browser, markup

Prompt how to solve a problem, please.

I have a `div` containing text.

It is necessary that the text was in a circle.

[alt text http://img153.imageshack.us/img153/4861/56160971.gif](http://img153.imageshack.us/img153/4861/56160971.gif)

From what to me to start to solve the given problem? Can be methods javascript (on a site it is connected jQuery)?

P.S.
The decision should be crossbrowser.

Comment: кроссбраузерное > Cross browser compatible.. 

What is it you actually want to do? This is very unclear.. Could you please post up some code or a link to what you'd like help with?

Thanks.

Comment: To be honest I didn't understand a single word of what you wrote. Please try to be more clear and/or provide sample sketches of what it should look like / do

Comment: I has very badly explained that it is necessary for me. I have corrected a question. Thanks for your remarks.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are looking for this plugin:

http://nicodmf.github.com/TextMorph/en.html

Here are some demos:

http://nicodmf.github.com/TextMorph/demos/jquery.html

Comment: Good job on deciphering what he wanted!

Comment: I got it the first time i read that too... ;) ... Nevertheless.. an interesting question.... and +1 for the links...!

Comment: Yes, references interesting. But it not that is necessary. It is my fault that I could not ask a question well. I have corrected a question.

Answer (score 1):

Can I guess at a translation?

- you have a div containing text
- you don't know the size, perhaps because the div size is linked to the browser width / screen resolution / parent div
- you want a circle to "spin round the block" (have animated movement?) ie you want a circle to move round the div that contains the text
- you want this to always happen irrespective of the size of the text-container div
- the effect will be kind of like a 10,000 metre runner running round a track except the size of the track is dynamically generated

Not a solution, but I think a translation might be a better first start... Is this anywhere close to what you are trying to describe?

Comment: @odavy, I am sorry. I has very badly explained that it is necessary for me. I have corrected a question. Thanks for your remarks.

Answer (score 1):

I can think couple of methods:

1. Wrap the text block by bigger element, resize it so that the circle will fit (you will need some serious math skills!) and use cross-browser [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) library to draw a circle on it.
2. Based on the width & height of text block, adjust top/bottom padding until the box is square and choose best matching background from different size pre-drawn images.

Sample code (using jQuery) to get the second idea, totally untested:

```
var images = [300, 200, 100];  // image dimensions from biggest to smallest
var textbox = $('#my-textbox');
var padding = 20;  // base padding, choose your own
var w = textbox.width();
var h = textnox.height();
var filler = (w > h ? (w - h) : (h - w)) / 2;  // how much extra padding needed?
var pver = w > h ? filler : padding;  // padding vertical
var phor = w > h ? padding : filler;  // padding horizontal
textbox.css({ paddingTop: pver, paddingBottom: pver,
              paddingLeft: phor, paddingRight phor });
$.each(images, function(i, dimension) {
    if (dimension < textbox.width())
        textbox.css('backgroundImage', 'url(/img/circle_' + dimension + '.png)');
});
```

Comment: @Yaggo, Raphael too heavy library that it to connect for one only this thing. Whether there is a decision on pure javascript?

Comment: Added a second idea, no external libraries needed.

Comment: Preliminary drawn pictures do not suit. The text can be any size (it is impossible to draw the picture under every size test).

Comment: Draw just one big enough picture and use it as downscaled <img> element instead of background? Use absolute positioning / z-index to get it behind the text box.